# VB.Net: How to install plugins/extensions in CEF?

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome-extension, chromium-embedded

I am making a vb.net web browser, and for the browsing engine I am using [ChromeWebBrowser.Net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chromewebbrowse/?source=recommended). To improve the users browsing experience, I want to add the plugin "Adblock Plus". I cannot figure out how to add this plugin, in my code I have `ChromeWebBrowser1.AddPluginDir("C:\MySurf Plugins\")` I don't know what type of files/folders I need to put in the custom plugin directory in order for adblock to work. I copied the plugin folder from Google Chrome, and added it in that folder, but it did not do anything. Can anyone help me out here? Chrome plugins should be compatible, since ChromeWebBrowser.Net uses CEF3.

Comment: Adblock Plus is not a _plugin_, it's an _extension_. Quite different.

Comment: Sorry, I am new with CEF. Is there any way I could get any Ad blocking software in CEF? @Xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer *may* be outdated, but I doubt it.

**No, it's not possible to easily use a Chrome extension in CEF.**

*Source: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10242*

> Chrome extension APIs are named "chrome.*". To use extension APIs in CEF you would need to re-implement them on top of CEF's binding capabilities.