# Will Chrome Packaged Apps work on Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)?

Tags: google-chrome-app, chromium-embedded

I am looking to use Chrome Bluetooth API's to run on Chromium Embedded Framework. Would like to know will it work? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net: How to install plugins/extensions in CEF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494323/vb-net-how-to-install-plugins-extensions-in-cef)

Answer (score 1):

CEF does not support Chrome packaged apps. Chrome extensions API is not supported and without it a packaged app would be just a bundle of a javascript code running on a web page. If that's the case with your packaged app then you could make it work in CEF.